# Amazon s3 services integration with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am trying to integrate our s3 services with Oracle Apex application. After following this link :
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/integration-086636.html#S3

I build app which suppose to connect Amazon service and should return content of the buckets.

Additionally I added ACL rule to allow communication with amazon service following this extremely helpful article:

http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2010/03/17/oracle-11g-access-control-list-and-ora-24247/

I created following exception:

```
begin
   dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
         acl         => 'utl_http.xml',
         description => 'HTTP Access',
         principal   => 'my_user',
         is_grant    => TRUE,
         privilege   => 'connect',
         start_date  => null,
         end_date    => null
       );

  dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege (
         acl        => 'utl_http.xml',
         principal  => 'my_user',
         is_grant   => TRUE,
         privilege  => 'resolve',
         start_date => null,
         end_date   => null
       );


       dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
         acl        => 'utl_http.xml',
         host       => ' *.amazonaws.com’,
             lower_port => 80,
         upper_port => 80
       );

  commit;

end;
```

I also granted execute on utl_http for my user. Regardless, whenever I run app I get this error message:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130 ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
    Technical Info (only visible for developers)
    is_internal_error: false
    ora_sqlcode: -29273
    ora_sqlerrm: ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130 ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
    component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROCESS
    component.id: 5598811807578444
    component.name: Web Service Request
    error_backtrace:
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
    ORA-06512: at "APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 550
    ORA-06512: at "APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1171
    ORA-06512: at "APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS", line 397
```

Oracle 11g, Apex 4.2

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still getting `ORA-24247` so that suggests something is incorrect for your ACL. What users did you provide with connect rights?
You will need to give the connect rights to

- the parsing schema user
- the technical apex user current to the apex installation. For apex
  4.2 this is `APEX_040200`

Comment: I added code I used to create ACL exception. I am not convinced about ports, is it only 80 ? Also are you suggesting that I should replace 'my_user' with generic APEX one ? Will that mean that all apex users will be capable of using this exception ?

Comment: Don't confuse that apex user with users using apex. Granting the apex user the connect rights is the only way to make your external call possible from within apex. The apex user is a sort of proxy user by which apex uses/calls things in the db. I'm NOT suggesting to replace the parsing schema user: I'm saying AND-AND. I'd not say that your 'user' needs the rights, but it allows you to run things outside an application. The port I'm not sure of, that depends on the webservice. As a matter of test you can always first leave the port blank and then narrow it down afterwards.

Comment: It works! If I had to implement that for Apex 4.0 is username going to be APEX_040000 ?

Comment: Exactly. Don't forget that after an upgrade of apex (say, going to 4.2) that you'll need to adjust the acl aswell. Remove the old one, add the new one.

Comment: Thanks, it works and connects to amazon but it does not show any buckets and when I create new bucket it will display successful message but still will not show existing bucket list.